# C/C++: To access a position of a pointer of a given type is different to acess the same position of a pointer of another type?

Tags: c++, c, pointers

Lets take the two following pointer access:

```
char poBuffChar[100];

Case 1:

(void *)&poBuffChar[10];

Case 2:

(void*)(&poBuffChar)[10];
```

If I understand correctly, the first case I pick a member of my char buffer, pick a pointer to that member and convert that pointer (which is a `char*`) to a pointer to void. In the second case, well, actually I'm not sure what it does xD But what matter is that the first situation gives me a "warning: dereferencing to void*" (or something similar) while the second case gives me no warnings.

The problem is: by changing from case 1 to 2, am I dealing with the same results? That is, do the second code access the same data that the first one?

---

EDIT

Well, it seems there is a difference: running the code with the second case just gave a Segmentation Fault. But some clarification is still required (as well as some proposition on how to get rid of the warning now that I know the first available solution doesn't work)

Comment: you could print `poBuffChar`, `&poBuffChar`, `&poBuffChar[10]` and `(&poBuffChar)[10]` to see the difference

Comment: What is the usage context? Otherwise I'm not sure why this matters. Also, this seems like something you would not do in C++.

Comment: None of the lines given here involve dereferencing of `void` pointers. And the pointer in case 2 cannot be dereferenced just like the other one. Please copy error messages verbatim and show code corresponding to them.

Comment: @mch yeah, I thought about that option, but the specific code was inside a quite 'obscure' part of the application (which is supposed to run in Embedded Linux), so it wasn't without some job that I could do that. When that happens, I prefer to put the problem into public so not only I'll probably end up finding the answer, but also it might help others - specially in such more "conceptual" problems (note that it wasn't me who found the Segmentation Fault problem ;) )

Comment: @mafso warning message: `warning: dereferencing 'void *' pointer` using GCC in Linux Ubuntu inside Qt Creator with qmake compiling a C project. Precise code: `memcpy((&buffer_send[sizeof(_eth_send_data_header)]),(&buffer[num_start]),header.size_udp_atual);` , with "buffer_send" being a `char *` buffer with memory allocated with malloc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`&poBuffChar[10]` has the type `pointer to char` and  points to the 11th element of the array `poBuffChar`.

`(&poBuffChar)[10]` is the `11th element of an array of (arrays of chars of size 100)` whose first element allegedly is `poBuffChar` (the whole array). This element's type is `array of char of size 100`, much like `poBuffChar` itself. It points `10 * 100 = 1000` bytes beyond the beginning of the array.

[Coliru Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/46b1b1d068433b17)

Comment: Actually the whole expression `(&poBuffChar)[10]` has the type "array of chars of size 100" (namely the 10th element of the array of arrays which `&poBuffChar` points to); which in most cases decays to a pointer to its first element, so that it becomes a pointer to char, much like a naked poBuffChar. Think of `&` and `[]` as inverse operations.